# Magento 2 Getting an error "The requested qty exceeds the maximum qty allowed in shopping cart."

Tags: magento2, shopping-cart

code example:

```
class CustomAddToCart {
  public function __construct(
    \Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart $cart
  ) {
    $this->cart = $cart;
  }
  public function execute()
  {
    $product = ....
    $this->cart->addProduct($product, ['product' => $product->getId(), 'qty' => 1]);
    $this->cart->save();
  }
}
```

When the cart do the save Magento tries to change the quantity  of the last item currently in the cart into 2. Since all products in our website only have a stock quantity of 1 it can only be added in the cart once. So I do not know why Magento is doing this. Can anybody please help me if someone already had experience this.

[xdebug break point where last item in cart is increased from 1 to 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cBhSv.png)

[xdebug call stack trace of the trace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yvd2g.jpg)

Comment: Hello Meynard,
Please check below configuration which is global for all the products.

1. Stores > Configuration > Catalog > Inventory > Product Stock Options > Maximum Qty Allowed in Shopping Cart 

Secondly, you need to check the below configuration of the product for which the quantity is changing 

Catalog > Products > Edit the product which is having a problem while adding to the cart > Search for "Advanced Inventory" and click on it you will get Maximum Qty Allowed in Shopping Cart and change it to 1 (It can be anything) and don't forget to clear the cache.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you are doing great!

Please check below configuration which is global for all the products.

**1. Stores > Configuration > Catalog > Inventory > Product Stock Options > Maximum Qty Allowed in Shopping Cart**

Secondly, you need to check the below configuration of the product for which the quantity is changing. This setting will take the precedence on global setting so please do the product related changes with the help of below setting and try one more time.

**2. Catalog > Products > Edit the product which is having a problem while adding to the cart > Search for "Advanced Inventory" and click on it you will get Maximum Qty Allowed in Shopping Cart and change it to 1 (It can be anything)**

***3. *Don't forget to clear the cache*.***

Please take a look at the below link.
https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/18477

Thanks,
Sonu